# Is my positioning wrong?

Tags: html, css, positioning, margin, padding

I've used margins to position everything on my website that being positioning images, divs etc.. I need to know whether what Im doing is correct (in terms of position) could you please inspect my code? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/LUhb7/

examples of my margins

```
margin: -410px;
```

I understand that their are plenty of ways to position things on CSS. I am wondering, they way I have used margins in my CSS is it correctly done? Like instead of margins, shouldn't i be using other things such as float, position: relative etc.. ?

Comment: Can you include your code here rather than checking the question score ? [I didn't voted]

Comment: Looks like a valid question to me, but we respond better to [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Examples](http://sscce.org/). Try to whittle down your website to the minimum that still reproduces the error. I've had problems that I almost posted to StackOverflow, only to discover the root cause through whittling it down.

Comment: @Prashant All I want to know is, is my use of positioning correctly done? Like, should I use margins to position everything because it's working fine.

Comment: @TLama I'd put the code here, but the code is too long hence why I thought putting it in a pastebin would solve it

Comment: @AdzT1. Would you be able to get a working version up in JSFiddle. It will be much easier to decipher your actual problem rather than navigating between two links

Comment: @Sico http://jsfiddle.net/LUhb7/ there you go!

Comment: Thanks @AdzT1. Now if you edit your post with that and explain what is going wrong in the JSFiddle example, they may unlock your post

Comment: @Sico before I go further, I just want to know if my use of positioning is done correctly

Comment: @Sico updated! do you understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: @AdzT1 That's a wide question as there are many ways to achieve what you want in css, not one standard way. You have specified -400 as a margin. How do I know if that was intentional or not. That's why you need to be more specific

Comment: @Sico Updated, to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, DIVs are block elements which mean they flow beneath each other on the page. To get round this, you have specified margins on .box3 to move it next to .box2.

Another way to do this is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box">...</div>
   <div class="box">...</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper {clear:both;}
.box {float: left;}
```

This will give you the same effect. http://jsfiddle.net/FKBXQ/

Comment: Am I using the positioning correctly? Like should I use margins in that way? Because my margins are going crazy like -400px

Comment: Would using this be better? float: left position: relative; left: -30%; top: 40%

Comment: Personally I would use either floats and margins OR positioning but not both

Comment: Or instead of left: -30%; should i use right: 30%; ?

Comment: This is better on the post or in a new question

Comment: so you are trying to say what I did with margins is correct? Like my intentions of positioning using margins is cool? basically, can margins be used for positioning like how I did with -410px margins?

Comment: wouldn't say correct, just different